# HTML: How to redirect users to a variable url depending on their form input?

Tags: html, redirect, replace, forms

I've the problem that I want to use a payment system for my website for which I need to setup a system by which users get redirected to a url. This url needs to contain their own username on the location of the text `[USER_ID]`. The problem is that the url is built up like: `&uid=[USER_ID]&widget=m2_1` How can it get the `[USER_ID]` to change to exactly the same thing the user entered in a form before:

```
<form>
User: <input type="text" name="url1" id="url1" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Goto URL" onclick="redirect()">
</form>
```

And use the text the user submitted in the form box to get it on the place of [USER_ID]?

Comment: What about just redirecting the user after a successful form post?

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses jquery's [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to retrieve the value from the form input, then it concatenates it to the url. I hope you are doing *some* sort of user validation...

```
function redirect()
{
   ...
   var userId = $("#url1").val();
   var url = "redirect" + "&uid=" + userId + "&widget=" + widget;
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the redirect function that you are using, you can extract the data of the input box and redirect the user as

```
window.location = yoursite.com/yourpage.php?user_id=getElementById('url1').value;
```

Comment: I dont exacty know how to set it up in my HTML code. I now did it:         <form>
User: <input type="text" name="url1" id="url1" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="redirect(yoursite.com/yourpage.php?user_id=getElementById('url1').value;)">
</form>
<script>
<action:"goto">window.location = yoursite.com/yourpage.php?user_id=getElementById('url1').value;
</script>      but this appears not to be working

Answer (score 0):

If you attach an action attribute to the form tag say : `action='submit.php'`, and also attach `form` tag `method='post'`. Also, add a  then in the file 'submit.php' you would use the following code (indexed by the name attribute of the input tag). The last line is how to do a redirect in php.

```
<?php

  //submit.php

  $root = 'www.foo.bar/';
  $user = $_POST['user'];
  $url= $root.'&uid=[$user]&widget=m2_1';
  header('Location: $url');

?>
```

checkout:
http://myphpform.com/php-form-tutorial.php
also, if you prefer to use javascript or jQuery you can use ajax to post to the server and get the response.